# SharePoint 2013 on premises get user sid using Javascript

Tags: 2013

Is it possible to get user SID using Javascript in SharePoint on premises site ?

I can see it in the sourceInfo html generated but how to get it ?

Its the current logged in user I am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_spPageContextInfo.systemUserKey
```

It gave me what i needed. I donnot have had to call the sharepoint then wait.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager.getMyProperties Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj679865(v=office.15).aspx) in JSOM or [GetMyProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn790354(v=office.15).aspx#bk_PeopleManagerGetMyProperties) endpoint in REST for that purpose.

**Example**

The following example demonstrates how to rettrieve User `SID` property for current user using JSOM:

```
function getMyProfileProperties(success,error)
{
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var pm = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(ctx);
    var myProperties = pm.getMyProperties();
    ctx.load(myProperties);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function(){
        success(myProperties);
      },
      error);
}

//Usage
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
   SP.SOD.executeFunc('userprofile', 'SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager', function() {
       getMyProfileProperties(
          function(profileProperties){
              console.log(String.format('Current user SID : {0}',profileProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['SID']));
          },
          function(sender,args){
              console.log('Error occurred while getting user profile properties:' + args.get_message());
          }    
       );
   });
});
```

**References**

[How to: Retrieve user profile properties by using the JavaScript object model in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj920104(v=office.15).aspx)